# Dependency injection in window service class

Tags: c#, windows-services, autofac

Need a clue to inject properties in my service class in a Windows Service using Autofac.

```
public partial class SomeService: ServiceBase
{
    public ILogger {set;get;} // <- how to inject this using AutoFac
    public IRepository {set;get;} // <- how to inject this using AutoFac

    protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
    {
        // use ILogger and IRepository
    }

}
```

thank you.

Comment: Can't use the constructor?

Comment: Show your Main function that performs a `new SomeService()`.

Answer (score 0):

OnStart method is like Main method of application and, I think, you should just initialize your container here.